# Why can't I include the cuchar header file?

Tags: c++, header

It says [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cuchar/) that

> This header, first introduced in C by a Technical Report extending C99, is fully supported by the latest standards of C and C++ (both published in 2011).

Yet, when I try to `#include <cuchar>` or `#include <uchar.h>`, the compiler gives me a "file not found" error.

edit: I forgot to include. The compiler I'm using is MinGW. This is on Windows 10.

Comment: It might be worth adding which compiler, OS etc

Comment: did you use some kind of IDE like CodeBlock or DevC++? Anyway, have you checked includes directory where your compiler always check for `include` directive?

Comment: Do you expect to guess everyone to guess which compiler you're using? This header does exist with gcc.

Comment: Although this seems [reproducible on Ideone](https://ideone.com/DVY2Nx)

Comment: @BagusTesa I used Notepad++

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, I forgot to include mention which compiler I was using. What am I doing wrong in my program that I can't include the header?

Comment: anything you pass through compiler? and even the make file (if any)? also, your GCC is it MinGW or Cygwin? Have you take a look on the gcc's include directory?

Comment: @BagusTesa, I'm using MinGW. I actually just checked the MinGW folder that was installed in my system. I tried searching for "uchar" or "cuchar" but the searches turned up nothing. I also searched for something common like "vector" or "iostream" and those searches were successful. I'm guessing based on this that my compilar does not have the uchar header?

But to answer your question, do you mean command line arguments? the only thing I write is "g++ -std=c++11" before the file name to be compiled

Comment: yep, your last comment gave us lots information. so... it did not have `uchar` and cuchar`... weird. perhaps the solution is around reinstalling MinGW packages.. but i'm not sure, it's been a while from my last time fiddling MinGW.. *But to answer your question, do you mean command line arguments? the only thing I write is "g++ -std=c++11" before the file name to be compiled*  - yes, we could pass includes via command line arguments anyway, so, it is best to look into it too.

Comment: @BagusTesa I went back to my mingw installer and looked through the available packages to see if I can find anything related to uchar. I found 4 entries with the description "libunistring: Library for manipulating Unicode strings." The name of the packages are all "mingw32:-libunistring". I added them to the installation but it's still not working

Comment: I am having a similar issue, I tried to commit a [Pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray/pull/396). It is compiling and working fine on my windows machine but failing on the Continuous integration builds (semaphore and travis). I'm only using one function (c16rtomb) so maybe there is an easy way to do without?